# jQuery hover overwrite the CSS a:hover color

Tags: jquery, css, hover

I have a `<div />` that contains a image and a anchor. The anchor has an a CSS attribute for a:hover that changes the color. It works! The problem is that I've added a jquery.hover() on the image that changes the color too for the anchor. When I try to hover the text directly, and not the `<div />` containing the image, it doesn't works.

Code and example: http://jsfiddle.net/FGVSK/

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the second function you're passing to the `hover` function, instead of setting the `color` property to the original hex value, you should simply reset it to nothing:

```
$(this).next('a').css('color', '');
```

Here's a demo of this: http://jsfiddle.net/yijiang/FGVSK/1/

Answer (score 0):

The jquery will override the css poperty. You need to reset color by.

function() {
            $(this).next('a').css('color', '');
       }